# c++: array size in new-expression must be constant

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to declare a 2 dimensional array using a constant integer as the bounds, however this error still persists.

```
template <class Type>
matrixType<Type>::matrixType(){
    h = maxSize;
    w = maxSize;
    matrix = new Type[maxSize][maxSize];
    defaultFill();
}
```

matrix is declared as:

```
Type* matrix;
```

and maxSize is declared as:

```
const int maxSize = 4;
```

Comment: Consider just using `std::vector` (or `std::array` if size is fixed at compile time). Forget about old C-style arrays.

Comment: How, when and where are `maxSize` declared and defined? Can you show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In C 2D arrays are double pointers, i.e. pointers of pointers. You need to allocate a list of pointers first, then allocate a list of Type for each pointer in the list of pointers.

Comment: You should post exact error text here actually.

Answer (score 4):

Briefly `new` operator has a following syntax: `new typename [items_count]`. `new Type[maxSize][maxSize]` expression tries to allocate array of `maxSize` of `Type[maxSize]` type and returns a pointer to `Type[maxSize]`. It is not possible to allocate multidimensional array with new. Using `Type[maxSize]` is illegal because `maxSize` is not known at compile time. If you want allocate a multidimensional array you should allocate an array of pointers to `Type` and then fill it with freshly allocated pointers to arrays of `Type`.

```
Type * * matrix = new Type *[maxSize];
for(size_t row = 0; maxSize != row; ++row)
{
    matrix[row] = new Type[maxSize];
}
```

or as a single array

```
Type * matrix = new Type[maxSize * maxSize];
```

Comment: `maxSize` should be usable as a constant expression in this context

Comment: @PasserBy Even if `maxSize` was a constant expression op's code wouldn't work because `matrix` type is different from new result.

Comment: I'm not objecting about that, just pointing out using `Type[maxSize]` is legal